# IMAP returns error in command on fetch headers

Tags: header, command, imap, fetch

I'm trying to get message headers from Courier IMAP
I'm running the command

```
FETCH 3 BODY[HEADER]
```

where 3 is the message id, but all I get is the response

```
Error in IMAP command received by server.
```

I've also tried the following

```
FETCH 3 (BODY[HEADER])
```

But that doesn't work either, same error

This has been working fine in hMailServer, but not in Courier IMAP

What's wrong with this command?

**EDIT:**

The problem was I wasn't selecting a mailbox correctly. the fetch command itself is fine. thanks to [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442918/max) :)

Comment: Have you selected a folder?  I get that exact error if I do that with no folder selected.  I also assume you've provided a tag, and are just not showing us that.

Comment: yes, you were right! it was a mailbox selection issue. i was trying to select a mailbox but long story short, i wasn't doing it correctly in my code and the mailbox wasn't being selected. thank you!

Comment: I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected a folder? I get that exact error if I do that with no folder selected.